# Why do my cloudsql postgres users have access to all databases?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I'm trying to follow the docs for setting up the IAM postgres integration with cloudsql: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/create-manage-iam-users#grant-db-privileges

But this is tripping me up. I create a user like this: `gcloud alpha sql users create service-account@myproject.iam --instance=myserver --type=cloud_iam_service_account --project myproject`

I can login as the user, but this postgres users has like super user levels of access. I can connect to any DB and perform CRUD on any DB. The docs seem to imply this should not be: `Before a user or service account can connect to a database or run queries against it, they need to be granted privileges for that database`

Apparently not because as soon as I created that `cloud_iam_service_account` user it could do pretty much anything.

It looks like the users are added to the `cloudsqliamserviceaccount` postgres group. If I remove them from that group IAM integration is turned off and they can't login.

How am I supposed to control access for these IAM users in postgres? I only want them to have access to their own specific databases.

When I do a `\l` under `Access privileges` I see no explicit grants for the IAM user or the `cloudsqliamserviceaccount` role so not sure where it is getting this permission. The `cloudsqliamserviceaccount` role is also not a member of any other role.

How do I even see where these privileges for these users are coming from?

Comment: No idea about what Google did to the software, but in PostgreSQL you would control access with the `pg_hba.conf` file and permissions on the database object.

Comment: The permissions are all managed in Postgres. So you might try to revoke all permissions and then re-grant just the appropriate permissions.

Comment: the users are added to the `cloudsqliamserviceaccount` role. But I cant see how its getting privileges to connect to and do CRUD on all DBs. the cloudsqliamserviceaccount role is required because when it is removed it breaks the IAM integration

Comment: Hi OP. This is working as intended. Please review the first statement on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/create-manage-iam-users#creating-a-database-user). "You add the user to each instance that contains the databases that the user needs to access. Once added, the user can access all the instances and databases in the project". I understand your confusion. We're already working on improving the documentation.

Comment: @Dondi  good to know. Also though, docs should include guidance for how to properly restrict access. I have 8 microservices, each has their own service account and postgres DB and I only want them to be able to access their own DBs- common use case. So how do I do grants correctly? I already tried removing the cloudsqliamserviceaccount role and that broke the IAM integration. Google needs to provide guidance on how to support this common use case with cloud sql postgres. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Red. We're still working at the documentation. Meanwhile, I opened a public issue tracker so you can track the issue here along with other readers who might encounter the same problem: https://issuetracker.google.com/187883194. After visiting the link, please indicate that you're affected by the issue.